# How to debug inconsistent crash to SIGABRT and NSLayoutConstraint constant is not finite! That's illegal. constant:nan

Tags: ios, swift

I have looked through all the SO answers and everything seems to point to a divide by zero issue, however, I am not dividing by zero anywhere (at least that I can tell).

Total error I get:

> 2017-08-17 10:08:49.760586-0500 APP[90643:6605106] *** Assertion failure in -[NSLayoutConstraint _setSymbolicConstant:constant:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Foundation/Foundation-1350/Layout.subproj/NSLayoutConstraint.m:711
>   2017-08-17 10:08:49.761100-0500 APP[90643:6605106] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSLayoutConstraint constant is not finite!  That's illegal.  constant:nan firstAnchor: secondAnchor:(null)'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x18ccaafe0 0x18b70c538 0x18ccaaeb4 0x18d743760 0x18d6e4b40 0x18d6e4a04 0x102ac2b7c 0x102ac28c4 0x102abddf4 0x102abe038 0x192df4838 0x192e8f9a4 0x18cba06c0 0x18cb976fc 0x192df4ac0 0x192df45a8 0x19312d080 0x193069594 0x19305b630 0x192dcf28c 0x18cc589a8 0x18cc56630 0x18cc56a7c 0x18cb86da4 0x18e5f1074 0x192e41c9c 0x100038ec8 0x18bb9559c)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

As it does talk about .width, it seems that a divide by zero might be the issue, though I have triple checked my code and only have one division anywhere in the code:

```
self.startButton.frame = CGRect(x:self.view.frame.midX - (self.view.frame.midX / 2),y:self.view.frame.midY - 20,width:self.view.frame.midX,height:40)
```

Which is only there to center the button.

The crash is INCONSISTENT (which is always frustrating!), meaning that I can often repeat the same action and it works fine before a crash (sometimes after 2-3 times, other times, it happens right away...)

Here's the scenario and code around the issue:

I'm in a tabBarController (which has several tabs with all functions working fine) and receive a push notification (various push notifications work fine for setting all actions and pages using this same code).

```
let vc = currentViewController.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "\(rcView)")
 if vc != nil {
    currentViewController.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
```

This takes me to a UIViewController that includes a map, directions, various buttons, etc. (again, working great ).

Here is where we see the crash SOMETIMES....

When we click the 'Cancel' button on the controller

```
let cancelButton = UIButton(type: .system)
cancelButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.cancelIt), for: .touchUpInside)
```

which goes to the cancelIt function

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home") as! UITabBarController
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController
viewController.selectedIndex = 0
```

After this cancel, I can send another push notification and SOMETIMES it works, while other times, it crashes.

When it crashes, I get the error listed above and in AppDelegate.swift, a red line highlighting

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
```

with a "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" (which I have seen before and usually means a duplicate name on the main storyboard)

I'm pretty sure this is all related to the less-than-elegant (IMHO) way of moving from the tabBarController to the UIViewController, though why is it so inconsistent?

Other ways of doing this switchover are welcome - I did a lot of research on how others do it and this seems to be the most clean, but working 'sometimes' isn't going to make the client happy!

Comment: *"'m in a tabBarController ... and receive a push notification"* - ok, at that point, you `currentViewController.present()` -- ok, then tap a "cancel" button, and you.... `pop` ***and*** `dismiss` ***and*** change the `rootViewController` of the `keyWindow`??? If you `present()`, why don't you simply `dismiss()`? What is all the rest of it supposed to be doing?

Comment: I need to get back to the tabBarController ("Home") and select the first index there.  The "rest of it" is just to get back there (certainly I wish there was a more simple way to do that!)

Comment: Sorry, that still doesn't make sense... If you are currently looking at, let's say, Tab-3... and you `present()` a ViewController... your "root VC" is *still* the TabBarVC, with Tab-3 selected. When you tap "Cancel" in the presented VC, you can use a delegate / protocol to call a function in the TabBarVC - which would then set its own `.selectedIndex = 0` and `dismiss()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit more searching (and thanks to a tip I saw in a comment of another SO question - sorry, I lost the link...) on how to better read xcode crashes (https://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1), I found the issue to be in the Mapbox software I was using (https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-ios) and not in my code at all.....

The issue of inconsistency boiled down to the location changing from the Simulate Location and the push notification coming in as/at the 'destination' point (when the 'current location' and 'destination location' were the same, MapBox software was coming up with a nan).

I fixed that by doing a check for nan (.isNaN) though got another crash a bit later.....

Now, I've updated the SDK and am fighting other issues (one being that we no longer get the voice - another that the Simulate Location seems to not be working.....  AARRGGHH!) but at least the particular issue in the question is answered - it was in the library!

Comment: Thanks for you comment, I got an app crash about constraint, after use exception breakpoint, it stop at crash line code. Amazing!

Answer (score 0):

```
self.dismiss(animated: true) { [weak self] in
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home") as! UITabBarController
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController
    viewController.selectedIndex = 0
}
```

Try calling the dismiss with a completion handler. Oh, and why do you pop first and then dismiss? Is your map controller presented or pushed? Maybe you don't need both.

Comment: thanks for the idea - I tried it and (as well as it complaining that "self" was declared but never used...) the map controller went 'nuts' (crash showed all sorts of mapbox files I shouldn't have to mess with!) - going back to the way I did it before worked again.

As for the presented/pushed, as stated in the original text, it is presented when the push notification comes in.